# Lock screen doesn't turn on by full screen intent filter on Android 14

Tags: android, kotlin, intentfilter, lockscreen, android-14

I've set configs due to [documentation](https://source.android.com/docs/core/permissions/fsi-limits). The lock screen is turned on in Api<34 and emulator API 34 but not in real device Android 34. Here's the code:

```
  fun turnOnScreenLock(activity: AppCompatActivity) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
            activity.setShowWhenLocked(true)
            activity.setTurnScreenOn(true)
            val keyguardManager =
                activity.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager?
            keyguardManager?.requestDismissKeyguard(activity, null)
            activity.window.addFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON or
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON)
        } else
            activity.window.addFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED or
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
            )
    }
```

Also here is the manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
...
<activity
            android:name="de.netalic.messenger.ui.videocall.IncomingCallActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/MainActivityTheme"
            android:showWhenLocked="true"
            android:turnScreenOn="true"
            android:showOnLockScreen="true"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"/>
```